# Asp.net 3.1 Web API template can't connect with Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am new to .Net, I am doing a tutorial where I am creating an API with **ASP.Net 3.1**

In my environment, I am on a Windows machine, my browser is Chrome and I am using VS Code to edit my project and Postman to receive responses from my API

I have been trying to run my WebAPI template, create my project by typing: `"dotnet new webapi -n api"`

Everything was fine, when the project was created, restored, and ran, everything went well in CMD.

Now when I go to `localhost:5001/weatherforecast` my browser shows **err_empty_response** and when I use **Postman** and I don't get any response from the get method

Comment: What exactly is /weatherforecast?

Comment: Is the route defined by default from the **CLI** `dotnet new webapi` command

Comment: @KlausGütter Is the configuration that pops out from the template when you create a new api project with **.Net 3.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use https url You try postman settings SSL certificate verification disable it.